# Is there an event that deal with after window.scrollTo method is fired?

Tags: javascript, windows, events, scroll

Hello  Guys is there a way to be notified  after window scrolls using this method `window.scrollTo(0, 500)`. In my case , I have scrolled up the window (vertical scroll ) to position `500px` . I am looking for an `event` or `way`  to  deal with  after window scroll gets 500px  .If you see this example , `alert(window.scrollY)` don' t return the value passed to `scrollTo` method  which is expected to be `500px` but return `0` (init scroll )

```
window.scrollTo(0,500) ; // fired scroll 
alert(window.scrollY)  // check the scroll value , return 0
```

**NB :Any tip will be helpfull**

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Comment: [MDN scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)

Comment: Try changing x to y maybe?

Comment: _"Any tip will be helpfull"_ - Don't just ask for option _X_. Explain what you're trying to accomplish, and how _X_ might help you with that. Maybe there's a better option _Y_ for your problem you haven't thought about yet - like the [Intersection Oberver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: Checkout intersection observer too.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API